# AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit' with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I was working on a discord bot, that should edit its own message on a command, and I tried many things, but I kept getting the `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit'` Error, my code is this:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="title")
embed.set_author(name="name", icon_url="image")
embed.add_field(name="name", value="some text", inline=True)
channel = Client.get_channel(channel-id)
msg = channel.fetch_message(message-id)
await msg.edit(embed=embed)

# Also: I've "censored" the ID's
```

Apperently my error is at `await msg.edit(embed=embed)` Please help, I have no idea, I've searched throught the whole internet and I found nothing really helpful. Thanks

I've tried awaiting the `msg.edit()` function, as you see, but it still isn't working.

Comment: `channel.fetch_message` is the coroutine; you need to wait for it to complete before `msg` is an actual message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`channel.fetch_message` is the coroutine. If you don't use `await` on *it*, you get the `coroutine` object, not the ultimate result of the coroutine.

```
msg = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
msg.edit(embed=embed)
```